# How to find user in Azure AD B2C with regex using Graph Api?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api

Is it possible to find users in Azure AD using a regex with microsoft Graph api. Like I want to fetch all the users with email address like 'test[0-9]*@somedomain.com'.

Can we do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

At present, the Microsoft API supports the [OData Query Parameters](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/query_parameters#filter-parameter) to help customize the responses.

> Is it possible to find users in Azure AD using a regex with microsoft Graph api.

No, it doesn't have this feature currently. You may submit the [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory) to azure team.